# Map the variables in executable to memory segments

Tags: linux, memory-layout

Is there a tool in Linux which maps the different variable in an executable to it corresponding memory segments.

For example, if i have a initialized global variable `int x = 10` in my executable, the tool should show that the variable belongs to `.data` segment of the executable in a format similar to what is shown below.

`x         .data`

Comment: Why do you ask that? Why does it matters to you? You could use `nm` and `objdump` (perhaps write some `awk` to combine their output).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Is there an option in `objdump` which shows the output i want as mentioned above ?

Comment: Not in your format, but `objdump -t -h` could be useful (perhaps to be combined with output of `nm`). But you really should explain why you want that. Putting a global into `.bss` or into `.data` is IMHO an implementation detail of the building chain.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Ok i will tell u the need for this. Suppose a person starts to study the memory layout of a C program and he wants to know which variables goes to which memory segment. I am such a person. Hope now you understand the need. Curiosity in simple words

Comment: A global or static variable will go into `.bss` when it is not explicitly initialized (so left cleared), and to `.data` otherwise. For the particular rare case of global or static variables *explicitly* initialized to all zeros, it depends upon compiler optimizations.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I know the theory. But i just wanted to know whether there is a tool which visualizes the memory layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your executable is *not* stripped, then the [`nm` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/nm.html) (see also [Linux manpage for `nm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)) will do what you want - it prints a table of symbol names / addresses / types. It's got multiple output options; on Linux, the "sysv"-style formatting comes close to giving you what you want. Sample:

```
$ nm -f sysv /bin/perl
```

Symbols from /bin/perl:

Name                            Value Class      Type            Size Line Section

Bases.3             |000000000813019c|  d  |   OBJECT|0000000000000014|  |.data
F0convert           |00000000080c6905|  t  |     FUNC|00000000000000c6|  |.text
PL_AMG_names        |0000000008137c80|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000108|  |.data
PL_No               |0000000008137904|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000004|  |.data
PL_Yes              |0000000008137900|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000004|  |.data
[ ... ]
PL_curinterp        |0000000008138e88|  B  |   OBJECT|0000000000000004|  |.bss
PL_do_undump        |0000000008137910|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000001|  |.data
PL_dollarzero_mutex |0000000008138e58|  B  |   OBJECT|0000000000000018|  |.bss
PL_fold             |000000000812c020|  R  |   OBJECT|0000000000000100|  |.rodata
PL_fold_locale      |0000000008135c80|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000100|  |.data
PL_force_link_funcs |0000000008137da0|  D  |   OBJECT|00000000000006c8|  |.data
PL_freq             |000000000812c120|  R  |   OBJECT|0000000000000100|  |.rodata
PL_hexdigit         |0000000008137908|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000004|  |.data
PL_memory_wrap      |000000000812bfa3|  R  |   OBJECT|0000000000000013|  |.rodata
[ ... ]
PerlIO_setpos       |0000000008112134|  T  |     FUNC|00000000000000a6|  |.text
PerlIO_sprintf      |00000000081122ee|  T  |     FUNC|000000000000002a|  |.text
PerlIO_stdio        |0000000008138720|  D  |   OBJECT|0000000000000070|  |.data
PerlIO_stdoutf      |0000000008112066|  T  |     FUNC|000000000000003b|  |.text
[ ... ]If you do create an object file from the C sourcecode:

```
    int x = 10;
```

and run that through `nm`, it gives:

```
$ nm -f sysv xxxx.o


Symbols from xxxx.o:

Name         Value            Class        Type         Size     Line  Section

x           |0000000000000000|   D  |    OBJECT|0000000000000004|     |.data
```

Note the `Value` field reported by it is the *address* of said symbol, not the contents of the variable.

If you run `strip` over it, this table is removed though and all `nm` tells you is "no symbols".

Comment: Perfect! This is what i wanted